# How to find the tables affected in a PL SQL package?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have to find out the list of tables into which insertion or updation happens in my existing PL SQL package. I started analyzing the package. The concern is the package code runs in thousands of lines of code and in turn
calls many other packages. Also, the code was not written by me. I cannot run AWR report since it is Development environment.

Is there a way to get the tables into which insertion/updation happens after initiating the transaction?
Could a trigger be written to suit my requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-- plain
select *
from dba_dependencies
where name = 'PACKAGE_NAME' and owner = 'PACKAGE_OWNER'
and type in ('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY') and referenced_type = 'TABLE';

-- hierarchy
select distinct referenced_owner, referenced_name, referenced_type, referenced_link_name
from dba_dependencies
where referenced_type = 'TABLE'
start with name = 'PACKAGE_NAME' and owner = 'PACKAGE_OWNER' 
and type in ('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY')
connect by nocycle prior referenced_name = name and prior referenced_owner = owner
and replace(prior referenced_type, 'PACKAGE BODY', 'PACKAGE') = replace(type, 'PACKAGE BODY', 'PACKAGE')
and referenced_owner not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'OUTLN' , 'AUDSYS')
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: I wouldn't say your answer didn't help. But, as I said, a package calls another package and like that the depth is too high. So, I should keep on entering the package names in the above query.

Comment: I'll try if your query could be enhanced to list tables in all referenced packages.

Comment: Keep in mind, if the PL/SQL uses dynamic SQL, SQL embedded in string variables and run at execution time, the tables in these string SQL variables will not show as dependencies because the compiler never sees them.

Answer (score 2):

@akk0rd87 has the better answer -- `DBA_DEPENDENCIES`, with a `CONNECT BY` to get table usages by called procedures.

The only thing his answer wouldn't find is tables used directly because of dynamic SQLs (e.g., `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`).  For that, you can use fine-grained auditing.

To me, this approach is just a backup after you follow @akk0rd87's advice.

Since SO in not a free code writing service, I'll just give you the broad strokes.

1) Create a table to serve as your audit trail.  Make sure it has the following columns, at least:

- SCHEMA_NAME (30 chars)
- TABLE_NAME (30 chars)
- CALL_STACK (4000 chars)
- SQL_STMT (4000 chars)

2) Create a package to serve as an audit handler.  I *will* give you code for this, because it must follow the exact API I give to be usable with fine grained auditing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY xxcust_table_access_aud_pkg AS
  PROCEDURE audit_access ( schema_name VARCHAR2, table_Name VARCHAR2, policy_name VARCHAR2 ) IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO your_audit_table ( SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME, CALL_STACK, SQL_STMT )
    VALUES ( schema_name, 
             table_Name,
             substr(DBMS_UTILITY.format_call_stack,1,4000),
             substr(SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'CURRENT_SQL'),1,4000)
            )
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN 
      null;
  END;

END xxcust_table_access_aud_pkg ;
```

3) Loop through all the tables in your application schema and call `DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY` for each one.  E.g.,

```
FOR r IN ( ... all my tables ... ) LOOP
  DBMS_FGA.add_policy(object_schema=> r.owner,
                      object_name => r.table_name,
                      policy_Name => -- make up something unique, maybe table_name plus some number,
                      audit_condition => '1=1',
                      audit_column => null,
                      handler_schema => -- your schema,
                      handler_module => 'XXCUST_TABLE_ACCESS_AUD_PKG', -- the package above
                      enable => true);
```

4) Run your package and check the table for results

5) Repeat step 3, but drop the policies instead of adding them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a Trigger can be a solution, Below can be one of the solutions, with some manual effort though:

1. DO a grep on the main package to find the other package names, note the names of all packages including the main one.
2. Get the source code of all these packages from " all_source" table, with where clause on "NAME" attribute and specifying the package names identified above.
3. Spool the source for above packages in a text file and do a grep on insert and update commands.